# In React setState(), how to refill an array?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm doing a poker game practice, I want to re-shuffle the pokers each time when it is almost used up, but I cannot refill the pokers array with another array in setState(), the pokers array is empty at the end and throw the error.

```
    deal=()=>{
    // At the beginning, there are 104 pokers, there is a button to trigger this function;
    let tmpPoker = this.state.localPokers.pop();
    if(this.state.localPokers.length <= 5){
        let temp = shuffle([...allPokers]);
        console.log('Temp_outside');
        console.log(temp);
        console.log("Temp_outside")
        this.setState({
            localPokers: temp,
        },()=>{
            tmpPoker = this.state.localPokers.pop();
            console.log("Temp_inside");
            console.log(temp);
            console.log("Temp_inside"); 
            this.setState({
                localPokers: this.state.localPokers,
            },()=>{
                console.log("localPokers");
                console.log(this.state.localPokers);
                console.log("localPokers");
            });
            return tmpPoker
        });
    }
    this.setState({
        localPokers: this.state.localPokers
    });
    return tmpPoker
}
```

[This is console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVnff.png)

Comment: Your mutating state. Copy the state variables

Comment: you cant use pop on state. you are mutating the state.

Comment: also add the shuffle function

Answer (score 0):

You dont use the state inside `setState` like this, here is the correct way:

```
this.setState((state)=>({
    localPokers: state.localPokers
}));
```